# What is the terminology for an idle thread in concurrency?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

Sorry for the pedantic question, but I think there's a specific term for this that I'm struggling to call.

Suppose I have a set of concurrent processes and an X number of hardware threads, and I want to use those hardware threads as efficiently as possible, minimizing the idling time of each hardware thread, but some software uses the hardware threads inefficiently. I think there's a specific term for an inefficient use of resources when it comes to concurrency.

Comment: Dunno if it's what you're looking for, but I'd call that a lack of parallelism.   (and as a side note, simply minimizing idle-time isn't a sufficient goal; otherwise you could make any system "efficient" simply by spawning enough `while(1){}` time-wasting threads to saturate all the cores.  What you really want is to maximize throughput, not minimize idle-time)

Comment: Exactly so, and actually *increasing* idle time may accomplish that.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner ah I think throughput may be the terminology i was looking for, although I thought throughput is usually used in the context of data transfer?

Comment: I think *throughput* can be also used more broadly to mean "number of tasks completed per unit of time".

Comment: _"What is the terminology for an idle thread in concurrency?"_ - I would call that thread _sleeping_ or possibly _waiting_ (although it may be doing just a little more than nothing when waiting).